# Not able to access controllers scope from directive link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im little bit confused about the directive scope, here im not able to access controllers scope from inside the directive scope, I want to make two way bindings for controller properties **"draggingItem"** and **"droppingItem"**. Here I've used controllerAs format for avoiding the **$scope** dependency.

Here is the code: [CODWA](https://plnkr.co/edit/6AYfSalGyxyp9Ksb19QM?p=preview)

***Script.js***

```
(function(app){
'use strict';

app.

controller("mainController", ["$scope" , "$log", "$http", function($scope, $log, $http){
    var self = this;
    self.config = {};
    self.draggingItem ="N/A";
    self.droppingItem ="N/A";

    $http.get("config.json").success(function(data){
        self.config = data[0].config;
        $log.info("data: : "+self.config)
    });         
}])

//DRAG List - Item
.directive("dragItem", ["$log", function(){
    return{
        restrict: "A",
        controller: "mainController",
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl){
            el.draggable({
                 containment: ".container",
                 cancel: false,
                 revert: true
            });
        }
    }
}])

//DROP List - Item
.directive("dropItem", ["$log", function($log){
    return{
        restrict: "A",
        controllerAs: "main",
        controller: "mainController",
        scope: {
            draggingItem : "=",
            droppingItem : "="
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, main){
            el.droppable({
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    main.draggingItem = angular.element(ui.draggable).context.innerText;
                    main.droppingItem = angular.element(el).context.innerText;
                    $log.info("dragitem: "+main.draggingItem+"      dropItem: "+main.droppingItem);
                    ui.draggable.draggable("option", "revert", false);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}])

//DRAG List
.directive("dragList", function(){
    return{
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        template:  "<span ng-transclude></span>"+
                        "<ul>"+
                            "<li ng-repeat = 'dragItem in main.config.draggables' >"+
                                    "<button drag-item>{{dragItem}}</button>"+
                            "</li>"+
                      "</ul>"           
    }
})

//DROP List
.directive("dropList", function(){
    return{
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        template: "<span ng-transclude></span>"+
                      "<ul>"+
                            "<li ng-repeat = 'dropItem in main.config.droppables'>"+
                                "<button drop-item>{{dropItem}}</button>"+
                            "</li>"+
                      "</ul>"   
    }
})
```

})(angular.module("mainApp", []))

***config.json***

```
    [{"config" : {"draggables" : ["drag_1", "drag_2", "drag_3", "drag_4"],
    "droppables" : ["drop_1", "drop_2", "drop_3", "drop_4"]}}]
```

***index.html***

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Angular JS Views</title>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <link data-require="jquery-ui@*" data-semver="1.11.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery-ui@*" data-semver="1.11.2" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
  [ng-cloak]{display: none;}
  
  drag-list, drop-list{
   display: inline-block;
  }
  
  drag-list ul, drop-list ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 200px;
  }
  
  drag-list ul li, drop-list ul li {
   border: 1px solid;
   -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
   -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
   -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
   user-select: none;
  }
  
  drag-list ul li button, drop-list ul li button {
   position:relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 80px;
   background:none;
   border:none;
   cursor:pointer;
   background-color:rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.61);
  }
   </style>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="mainApp" ng-cloak="" ng-strict-di="">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="mainController as main">
   Drag Item: {{main.draggingItem}} = Drop Item: {{main.droppingItem}}
                           <h3>Drag and Drop Operation</h3>
      <drag-list>
        <h4>Draggable Item: </h4>
      </drag-list>
      <drop-list>
        <h4>Droppable Item: </h4>
      </drop-list>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here "N/A" not changing ...! I dont know why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see you have a directive called dropItem. With the an isolate scope with the following properties which are two way bound (=):

```
scope: {
            draggingItem : "=",
            droppingItem : "="
        }
```

So in your controller you would use the directive as follows:

```
<div drop-item dragging-item="main.someValueOne" dropping-item="main.someValueTwo"></div>
```

So back in dropItem directive when you modify the draggingItem or droppingItem e.g:

```
scope.draggingItem = 'stuff';
```

the `main.someValueOne` will be updated with the new value in the controller. This also works both ways. It's worth noting that for two way binding in the controller you do not use `dragging-item="{{main.someValueOne}}"` as this will pass in the evaluated expression i.e. whatever value main.someValueOne holds. You pass stuff in using dragging-item="main.someValueOne" so it is a reference.

Comment: Thanks @run yards, i tried, still its not working... 

"<button drop-item dragging-item='main.draggingItem' dropping-item='main.droppingItem'>{{dropItem}}</button>"+

and link function :

scope.draggingItem = angular.element(ui.draggable).context.innerText;

Comment: Event I tried with : bindToController it's not working
like;

scope:{},
   bindToController: {
    draggingItem : "=",
    droppingItem : "="
   },